# Svg circular slider color changing

Tags: javascript, css, svg, svg-animate, clip-path

I have following svg and i want to create a circular slider,
and the problem  is i can't found anything related to changing
stroke color of part of image.

```html
<svg width="221px" height="221px" viewBox="0 0 221 221" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
          <pattern id="pattern" width="100%" height="100%">
            <path  d="M110.5,221 C171.527465,221 221,171.527465 221,110.5 C221,49.4725351 171.527465,0 110.5,0 C49.4725351,0 0,49.4725351 0,110.5 C0,171.527465 49.4725351,221 110.5,221 Z"
              id="path-1"></path>

            <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
            </mask>
          </pattern>
          <defs>
           

            <path d="M110.5,221 C171.527465,221 221,171.527465 221,110.5 C221,49.4725351 171.527465,0 110.5,0 C49.4725351,0 0,49.4725351 0,110.5 C0,171.527465 49.4725351,221 110.5,221 Z"
              id="path-1"></path>
            <mask id="mask-2" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="221" height="221" fill="white">
              <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
            </mask>
          </defs>
          <g id="Final" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="url(#psattern)" fill-rule="evenodd" opacity="0.69921875" stroke-dasharray="1,4">
            <g id="voor" transform="translate(-77.000000, -230.000000)" stroke="#F5A623" stroke-width="48">
              <g id="fi-strokes" stroke-width="48">

                <g id="Gup" transform="translate(0.000000, -44.000000)">

                  <g id="Gup-5" transform="translate(20.000000, 111.000000)">
                    <g id="rp-4">
                      <g id="und" transform="translate(57.000000, 163.000000)">
                        <g id="reen">
                          <g id="Dl">
                            <g id="faded-ts">
                              <use id="Oval" mask="url(#mask-2)" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
                            </g>
                          </g>
                        </g>
                      </g>
                    </g>
                  </g>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
```

How to change part of image on mouse/touch events to another color?
I tried:

1. clip-path - i couldn't create smooth color changing.
2. linear-gradient - same problem

Any Tips?

Comment: What do you mean by "slider"?  Do you mean something like a circular progress bar?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau https://baijs.com/tinycircleslider/ something like this

Comment: So you want an image slider?  Why did you say you want "smooth color changing" then?  In any case, this question is a bit broad for Stack Overflow.